# No connection to mysql from servlet

Tags: java, mysql

I have a dedicated root server with CentOS and Apache Tomcat 7.
The Servlet in Tomcat7 works well, but dont get a connection/data from the database.

On my local system with eclipse it worked well. I exported the database from my local system and imported it with phpmyadmin on the server.

Same username, same passwort.
As host ive tried

```
final String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/table"; and
final String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table";
```

What could be the Problem? I dont know what to do.

Comment: Are you sure you have a mysql database installed in your database server, there's a communication established between your server hosting the web applications (where tomcat is installed) and your database server and you use the right credentials to access to your mysql engine?

Comment: You forgot to tell what happens instead. The answer is usually just straight in the exception and stack trace.

Comment: Nothing happens instead, no exeption in the log file, there is just no result.
the database server was preinstalled but phpmyadmin says mysql.
The database and tomcat server are on the same physical server. What do you mean with credentials?

Comment: If there was a connection problem, you would get an exception. Either you catch it and ignore it, or you have another bug in your code. Without more information (the code!), it's impossible to tell.

Comment: another information:
it takes around 8seconds until the database times out.

Comment: i check it again, there is no exeption...
is there a way in phpmyadmin to see/log all incoming connections and statements?

Comment: Ok sorry, I catched to much that i didnt see anything. Here is the exeption and the problem:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 0):

This `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is when you dont have the `mysql-connector-java.jar` in your classpath Download one fron [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.32) and put it in the classpath

Comment: how to put it in the classpath? where?

Comment: if you are using IDE in the ide's classpath or else Tomcat's lib folder